# How would I get a string from a different method if they are in the same class

Tags: java, bukkit

Right, I understand that this question has more than likely been answered before however it won't work in my circumstance.

So I have a string that I need to get into another method, here's the code...

```
public String createColoredMinuses(int amount, ChatColor colorOne, ChatColor colorTwo)
{
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(amount < 13);
if (amount % 2 == 0) {}
builder.append(ChatColor.BLUE + "-");
builder.append(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "-");
String string = builder.toString();
return string;
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String command,       String[] args)
{

  public static void createColoredMinuses()
  {
      Method1();
  }



  String b = builder.toString();
```

So what I want to happen is I want to be able to get the 'return string;' into the main part where all the commands go but into the 'String b=' part however I can't work out how to do it.

I hope this made sense to you! :P

Comment: Could you put the whole class so I can understand better what you mean?

Comment: You must learn Java! You can't learn Java like this. It's like trying to do a triathlon before learning how to swim. Based on what you've written so far, it looks like you need to declare `public static String createColoredMinuses` (static!), and then you can call `String b = createColoredMinuses(...)` from other methods. To understand how this works though, you must learn Java from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, after j get this sorted or if I really can't get it done I will learn Java, when I first started coding with Java nothing told me or advised me to learn Java first, I wish it did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just moved the StringBuilder as I couldn't work out how to call the method.
So that it was in the class with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be enough to have the builder as a private variable? I mean you literally want to use it privately in another method that you call later:

```
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

public String createColoredMinuses(int amount, ChatColor colorOne, ChatColor colorTwo)
{
    builder.append(amount < 13);
    if (amount % 2 == 0) {}
    builder.append(ChatColor.BLUE + "-");
    builder.append(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "-");
    String string = builder.toString();
    return string;
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String command,       String[] args) {

    public static void createColoredMinuses ()
    {
        Method1();
    }


    String b = builder.toString();
}
```

Another noticeable thing is that you have this method:

```
public static void createColoredMinuses ()
        {
            Method1();
        }
```

And it's inside the onCommand... this doesn't look right. You need to move this to somewhere else.

Comment: I'm just quoting his code with the relevant change. That inner method is not part of the question.

Comment: Yeah I know about the on command thing, I was trying a few different things that were suggested